# Comparar 2 arrays e salvar a diferença entre eles no banco de dados?

Tags: javascript, array, mongodb, comparação

Tenho 2 arrays de objetos, um deles é a composto por emails que vem do provedor através de protocolo IMAP e eu converto para objetos e depois coloco em um array todos ele.

O outro é um array de emails que eu busco no MongoDB e tem a mesma estrutura do primeiro email, segue exemplo:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59af03cb4a202223c4cf7bea"),
    "idEmail" : "DM5PR13MB10209695536A9A5B3119967CCD960@DM5PR13MB1020.namprd13.prod.outlook.com",
    "remetente" : "email@hotmail.com",
    "destinatario" : "email@gmail.com",
    "assunto" : "Teste de gravação no banco",
    "texto" : "Email diferente para gravar no banco\n",
    "box" : "INBOX"
```

}

O que eu quero fazer é uma função que compare os dois arrays, não exclua nada do DB, apenas salve as diferenças(no caso os emails mais recentes que estão vindo do provedor).

Porém os dois arrays não possuem o mesmo tamanho, o array que vem com os emails novos sempre será maior do que aquele que já está no DB.

O que eu estou preciso(e estou tentando) fazer é: **Comparar os dois arrays e adicionar no MongoDB apenas as diferenças.**

Só que já pesquisei bastante e até agora não achei nada que resolvesse o meu problema...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade, a resposta do Alexandre só retorna o que há no array 1 e não no array 2, quando na verdade a verificação deveria ser feita nos dois array, segue minha solução:

```
function validarDiferenca() {
        var r1 = [2,4,6,8];
        var r2 = [3,4,5,7,9];

        var apenasNoR1 = r1.filter(function (element, index, array) {
            if(r2.indexOf(element) == -1)
                return element;
        });

        var apenasNoR2 = r2.filter(function (element, index, array) {
            if(r1.indexOf(element) == -1)
                return element;
        });

        var todasAsDiferencas = apenasNoR1.concat(apenasNoR2);

        alert(todasAsDiferencas);
    }
```

Caso precise do array ordenado, aplique um sort no final com a lógica da ordenação. Mas acho que isso resolve seu problema.

Comment: Já vou testar aqui

Comment: Não consegui entender onde eu poderia botar essa função no meu código: https://codepen.io/LeonardoEbert/pen/mMYVjO?editors=1011

Comment: Implementei o código, porém ele salva o array todo, concatena os 2 arrays e grava tudo no banco, aqui está o código completo: https://jsfiddle.net/dxkyh3d8/1/

Comment: Não entendi qual o problema agora!  
Aliás, ja que você ta usando ES6, dê uma pensada sobre começar a usar arrow functions no seu código :)

Comment: To aprendendo ainda, e eu meio que consegui uma solução para comparar os arrays: https://jsfiddle.net/pzmb75oy/


Como os 2 arrays são a mesma sequencia, porém aquele que vem do provedor possui novos objetos no final, então eu cheguei os ID's das respectivas posições de cada array e agora preciso capturar aqueles que são os emails novos, agradeço se puder dar uma olhada naquele link do jsfiddle...

Answer (score 6):

Acredito que as soluções do @alexandre-cavaloti quanto do @carvbru podem ser usados, dependendo do requisito, pra mim não ficou muito claro qual das respostas se aplica a pergunta. De qualquer forma, gostaria apenas de acrescentar formas mais atuais de se fazer isso, que seria usando os novos recursos do javascript, neste caso [FILTER](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) e o [INCLUDES](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains).

Eu criei um pequeno script de demonstração https://jsfiddle.net/a35p607e/

Código:

```
function pegarDiferenca() {
    let r1 = [2,4,6,8];
    let r2 = [3,4,5,7,9];       
    let r3 = r1.filter( a => !r2.includes( a ) );

    console.log( r3 );
}

pegarDiferenca();
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2):

Essa função popula um array com a diferença entre 2 arrays:

```
function validarDiferenca()
    {
        var r1 = [2,4,6,8];
        var r2 = [3,4,5,7,9];       
        var r3 =[];
        r1.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
            if(r2.indexOf(element) == -1)
               r3.push(element);
        });

        alert(r3);
    }
```

Comment: Acredito que vai ser de grande ajuda, muito obrigado

Comment: Se ajudou, marque como útil. ;)

Comment: Amanhã vou ter tempo de ver e testar a vontade, agora não tenho mais tempo...